# Should I place a comma or "and" between the adjectives "frequent" & "new"?

Tags: adjectives, commas

I have a phrase "Frequent Automatic Renewals". Must there be a comma, or should I separate them with an "and"?

Comment: 1. I feel this has been already dealt with on this site. 2. There are subtle differences between using a comma, "and/&" and none in a list of adjectives, especially depending on context. In the OP's example, without knowing the context, no comma seems necessary.

Comment: Your question and example don't align.

Comment: Thanks. The context is the following - users of my web service can make a renewal of their profile once every 20 hours. And they must do it from the admin panel, by themselves. If they subscribe to certain paid options, they will get 1) frequent renewals (not 20, but 4 hours of interval) and 2) that frequent renewals will be executed by the system automatically. PLEASE help with the correct version.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a concept of automatic renewals, and you are discussing their frequency, you should use neither a comma nor *and*:

> The system enables frequent automatic renewals.

In this case, the relationships between the adjectives and the noun are different.

On the other hand, if renewals may or may not be frequent or automatic, the relationships been the adjectives and the noun are more similar.  Then you need a comma or *and*.  That case is illustrated in rhetorician's answer.

Comment: Thanks. The context is the following - users of my web service can make a renewal of their profile once every 20 hours. And they must do it from the admin panel, by themselves. If they subscribe to certain paid options, they will get 1) frequent renewals (not 20, but 4 hours of interval) and 2) that frequent renewals will be executed by the system automatically. PLEASE help with the correct version.

Comment: @ԱստղիկԹեհլերյան In that case I'd use a comma, or *and;* it doesn't much matter.  Or you could rephrase:  *renewals will be both frequent and automatic.*

Comment: @ԱստղիկԹեհլերյան Thanks are not necessary.  But please do upvote answers that you find helpful, and accept the answer you find most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Either way is fine.

> We prefer frequent and automatic renewals, unlike some people who prefer infrequent and deliberate renewals.
>
> We prefer frequent, automatic renewals, unlike some people who prefer infrequent, deliberate renewals.

Here is a completely different set of sentences, but the same "rule" applies:

> The boxer prefers short and intense fights.
>
> The boxer prefers short, intense fights.

Comment: It is also entirely possible to "prefer frequent automatic renewals," and I suppose that this would be the best way.

Comment: Thanks. The context is the following - users of my web service can make a renewal of their profile once every 20 hours. And they must do it from the admin panel, by themselves. If they subscribe to certain paid options, they will get 1) frequent renewals (not 20, but 4 hours of interval) and 2) that frequent renewals will be executed by the system automatically. PLEASE help with the correct version.

Comment: @ԱստղիկԹեհլերյան: Here are some suggested sentences:  "If you choose to renew your profile, you may do so from the admin panel by yourself, once every 20 hours. With certain paid options, however, you may choose to receive frequent and automatic renewals from our system in four-hour intervals." Don

Comment: @ԱստղիկԹեհլերյան: Don't mention it. My pleasure. Don